# Identifying the parallel degree which is forced in the session

Tags: sql, oracle, parallel-processing

In Oracle (12c) I can enable parallel DML:

```
alter session enable parallel dml;
```

Then I can check what status I have in my session:

```
SELECT pdml_status FROM v$session WHERE sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID');
```

So far so good. Now I can also force a parallel degree:

```
alter session force parallel dml parallel 13;
```

While above SQL also will show that I have set FORCE in my session, I couldn't find a way to see what DOP was forced (13 in the example). Anybody know how to get this?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select DEGREE, REQ_DEGREE from V$PX_SESSION 
WHERE sid = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'SID');
```

Comment: Nope. This would require that a parallel execution was already performed and obviously we could not distinguish the different settings possible like in:  

`code`
alter session force parallel dml parallel 11;  
alter session force parallel ddl parallel 13;  
alter session force parallel query parallel 17;  
`code`